# Web font that includes both alphanumeric characters and icons

Tags: website-design, icon, font-recommendation, web-fonts

There are lots of icon fonts, like [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/), [ionicons](http://ionicons.com/) and [others](https://css-tricks.com/flat-icons-icon-fonts/). But is there any web font that includes both text and icons? If not, do you know why?

My motivation to ask this is to be able cover the needs of icons and alphanumeric characters of a website loading only one web-font.

**EDIT:** As suggested in a comment, I know services like icoMoon or Fontastic, where you can build your own icon collections. Actually two of icoMoon icon collections include alphanumeric icons. But this is not what I mean, since those alphanumeric icons are not supposed to be used to display the text of a website.

What I'd like to find is a text web font, for example [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans), that includes also an icon collection by typing some character combination.
With that web font I could type *"car"* to write this word, or also type something like `&#xf1b9;` to display the icon of a car.

Comment: have you tried something like this - http://fontastic.me/

Comment: @MephistonX,I understood correctly what fontastic is, this is not what I mean. I edited my question and hope it's clear now. Thanks

Comment: I would think it would be easiest to modify a font to have those characters.

Comment: What you are asking for is a font that combines "Roman" characters (A-Z, 0-9, etc) and dingbats? I used to include some icons and drawings into some of my early fonts where some rarely used characters would be, but this is not a good practice in font design and neither is it a trend among designers because of how different designing icons and designing fonts is... Also, "icons" for the same idea exist in many styles, so you'd have to enjoy the font's design AND the icon's design. Easier to load 2 files...

Comment: FYI in your final paragraph you're talking about a font that uses *ligatures* for rendering icons. There's a few about, like [Symbolset](https://symbolset.com/). Ligatures require [OpenType support](http://blog.fontdeck.com/post/15777165734/opentype-1). Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of fonts (web & digital) combine alpha-numeric sets with icons.

Here is a simple example: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/asap-symbol

Please click on the "Glyphs" tab. You will see the full alpha-numeric set along with dozens of icons for use.

My recommendation, however, is to compile a custom font that contains the style of alpha-numeric glyphs that you're looking for (perhaps something like "Open Sans") and then add your icons into the other glyph locations. You could choose locations that would make sense for your personal project, for example, replacing the copyright glyph with a car as you suggested. Then you can simply type out

```
&copy;
```

and you will see your car.